# C# error saving Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm experimenting a lot, I'm trying to make my program a little more user friendly and that is where the problem starts.
At first the location of the excelfile was in a public static string and I had no problems. I've changed it to this:

```
 public string Excellocation()

    {
        string xlLocation;
        if (but_Browse.Text == "Zoek Excel")
        {

            xlLocation = @"E:\Levi\Documents\Verjaardagen.xlsx";
        }
        else //Only if I get into this part of my code I get the error
        {
            xlLocation = but_Browse.Text;
        }
        return xlLocation;
    }
```

And the button I use so the user can give me a location for the excel file is:

```
private void but_Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

            System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);

            //OR

            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);
            //etc
            but_Browse.Text = fileToOpen;
            this.but_Browse.AutoSize = true;
            But_Import.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

Reading the Excel-file is no problem, my program finds it and processes it, if and only if the user changed the location by using the "Browse button" I get a message from Windows that there is already an excel file with that name and if I want to replace it, If I click away that message, my code gives an error on the line that tries to save the excel file

```
            xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlWorkbook.Close(true);
            xlApp.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

xlWorkbook.Save() gives me this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
>   HResult=0x800A03EC    Message=Verjaardagen.xlsx can not be saved,
>   because it's read-only.

I have no idea why I don't get an error with the default location while I do get an error if use my button to give me that same location.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you amend your code to this: `xlLocation = but_Browse.Text; MessageBox.Show(xlLocation);` does that give you any clues?

Comment: The messagebox gives me this:

E:\Levi\Documents\Verjaardagen.xlsx

That is what there should be right?

Comment: Is it something to do with your `StreamReader`, does it have the file open when you attempt to save it?

Comment: I.e. Are you calling `reader.Close()` before you attempt to save the file?

Comment: after a click on a button, it opens Excel, does some stuff and then tries to save and close it. before I click that button, Excel is closed (No excel visible in taskmanager and I tried to reboot my pc to make sure excel isn't open anywhere)

Comment: What is going on here though: `System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen); //etc` Is this opening the Excel file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "reader.Close()" could you explain it a little more please? I'm still a noob with C#

Comment: Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Excellocation());
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

this is opening the Excel-file

Comment: What is the `StreamReader` reading (fileToOpen)?

Comment: I don't have those lines you said (system.IO.Streamr...) anywhere in my code. I didn't have any problems when my string excellocation was a static, therefore I didn't use it, but is it necessary to use it? ifso, where should I use it? before I open the Excel.application?

Comment: It's gets even weirder. If I click the button that reads my excel a second time, I don't get the error. I only get an error the first time that part of the code runs. The second time everything is fine (I have used try and catch)

Comment: It's on the 7th line in `but_Browse_Click`: `System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);`

Comment: Sorry about that, that is something I copied from Stack overflow :D
I use it to browse for a file and display that text in my windows form application. It's contains a string with the location of my excel file

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience Chris, I understand what you where trying to say and I feel stupid for not understanding it sooner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the file is read only when you try to write to it after going through but_Browse_Click? Are you closing the StreamReader? Try using

`reader.close();`

in but_Browse_Click.

Perhaps a better way would be:

`using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileToOpen))
    {
     //all code involving the reader in here
    }`

This automatically closes on completion.